# Simple JS Quiz Giving a Hard Time

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a school finals project in computer science and have to make a website that does something so to keep things simple I made a quiz, Im more of a pyhton guy myself but the school required JS so I tried... most of the website that doesnt do much (ie html and css) works but the quiz itself doesnt... I followed a YT tutorial and cant get it to work, I think its the JS part but then again I cant be sure...

I provided the code:

JS

```
const question = document.querySelector("#question");
const choices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".choice-text"));
const progressText = document.querySelector("#progressText");
const scoreText = document.querySelector("#score");
const progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#progressBarFull");

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = true;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestion = [];

let questions = [
  {
    question: "What is a CPU?",
    choice1: "The brain of a computer",
    choice2: "The power supply unit",
    choice3: "An array of fans",
    choice4: "The cooler",
    answer: 1,
  },
  {
    question: "What does CPU stand for?",
    choice1: "Capital Product Unified",
    choice2: "Central Processing Unit",
    choice3: "Capital processing Unit",
    choice4: "Computer Programming Utility",
    answer: 2,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a motherboard?",
    choice1: "Mum's baking board",
    choice2: "A list of married women",
    choice3: "The mother of the computer",
    choice4: "It is a PCB that connects all computer parts",
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a CPU cooler?",
    choice1: "A fridge that you put yout CPU in before building the PC",
    choice2:
      "An assembly designed to keep the CPU at safe operating temperatures",
    choice3: "A pair of sunglasses that the CPU wears to look cool",
    choice4: "A company that makes good CPUs",
    answer: 2,
  },
  {
    question: "What are the 2 main types of CPU coolers?",
    choice1: "Car radiators and house heaters",
    choice2: "Mini fridge and full-size fridge",
    choice3: "Air and water",
    choice4: "Earth and fire",
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: "What is RAM?",
    choice1: "Regulated Access Module",
    choice2: "Relative Amplitude Meter",
    choice3: "An American car company",
    choice4: "Random Access Memory",
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: "What is the RAM used for?",
    choice1: "Quickly opening and accessing recently opened stuff",
    choice2: "Racing your neighbor",
    choice3: "Storing all photos, apps, files and data long term",
    choice4: "Doing calculations",
    answer: 1,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a GPU?",
    choice1: "Grilling Purpose Utensils",
    choice2: "Graphics Processing Unit",
    choice3: "Graphics Power Unit",
    choice4: "Gender Prominance Unity",
    answer: 2,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a graphics card?",
    choice1:
      "The whole assembly including the GPU, PCB, audio outputs and in some cases a backplate ",
    choice2:
      "The whole assembly including the GPU, PCB, CPU, RAM, Motherboard and I/O.",
    choice3:
      "The whole assembly including the GPU, PCB, VRAM, cooler and in some cases backplate",
    choice4: "The whole assembly including the GPU, PCB, VRAM and cooler.",
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: "What is VRAM",
    choice1: "Video RAM, found on a graphics card",
    choice2: "Video RAM, found on a motherboard",
    choice3: "Video RAM, shared with the CPU",
    choice4:
      "Video RAM, either found on a graphics card or shared with the CPU.",
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: "What is storage?",
    choice1: "A way of storing data in a permanent way",
    choice2:
      "Short term, very fast memory for quickly opening recently opened things",
    choice3: "A hard disk for photos",
    choice4: "A USB stick for data",
    answer: 1,
  },
  {
    question: "What kind of storage drives are most commonly found in a PC?",
    choice1: "HDD, SSD, Hybrid",
    choice2: "USB, flash, NAND flash",
    choice3: "2.5in, 3.5in, m.2 (M - Key), m.2 (M+B - Key)",
    choice4: "Cache, L1, L2, L3, CD/DVD",
    answer: 1,
  },
  {
    question:
      "What are the most common storage drive sizes (not volume, physical size)?",
    choice1: "128GB, 256GB, 512GB, 1TB, 2TB",
    choice2: "5cm, 10cm, 15cm",
    choice3: "2.5in, 3.5in, m.2 (M - Key), m.2 (M+B - Key)",
    choice4: "80mm, 92mm, 120mm, 140mm, 180mm, 200mm",
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a PSU?",
    choice1: "Power System Utility",
    choice2: "Power Supply Unit",
    choice3: "Horsepower Unit",
    choice4: "Pressure Sensitive Utility",
    answer: 2,
  },
  {
    question: "What does a PSU do?",
    choice1: "Powers generators",
    choice2: "Supplies power to the GPU",
    choice3: "Converts electricity to heat",
    choice4: "Convert wall AC to DC and supply it to the PC",
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: "What is a fan?",
    choice1: "A person obsessed with another person such as a celebrity",
    choice2: "Air conditioner",
    choice3:
      "A carefully folded piece of paper that is used to move air with hand movements",
    choice4: "A motor driven propeller for moving air",
    answer: 4,
  },
  {
    question: "Do all PCs need a graphics card?",
    choice1: "Yes, all do",
    choice2:
      "No, some have an iGPU built into the CPU or in rare cases the motherboard",
    choice3: "No, some have an iGPU built into the CPU",
    choice4: "No, some have an iGPU built into the RAM",
    answer: 2,
  },
  {
    question: "What are the most common motherboard sizes in ASCEDING order?",
    choice1: "XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL",
    choice2:
      "SSI EEB, SSI CEB, XL ATX, EATX, ATX, SATX, MATX, MINI DTX, MINI ITX",
    choice3:
      "MINI ITX, MINI DTX, MATX, SATX, ATX, EATX, XL ATX, SSI CEB, SSI EEB",
    choice4: "There is no standard",
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question:
      "How many graphics cards can be installed in one PC (standard, excludes server grade hardware)?",
    choice1: "1",
    choice2: "2",
    choice3: "4",
    choice4: "8",
    answer: 3,
  },
  {
    question: "What is the recommended amount of RAM as of 2022?",
    choice1: "16GB",
    choice2: "32GB",
    choice3: "1.5GB",
    choice4: "256MB",
    answer: 1,
  },
];

const SCORE_POINTS = 100;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 4;

startGame = () => {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuestion = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuestion.length === 0 || questionCounter > MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore, score");

    return window.location.assign("/end.html");
  }

  questionCounter++;
  progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter} of ${MAX - QUESTIONS}`;
  progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

  const questionsIndex = Math.floor() * availableQuestion.length;
  currentQuestion = availableQuestion[questionsIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  choices.forEach((choice) => {
    const number = choice.dataset["number"];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
  });

  availableQuestion.splice(questionIndex, 1);

  acceptingAnswers = true;
};

choices.forEach((choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

    let classToApply =
      selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

    if (classToApply === "correct") {
      incrementScore(SCORE_POINTS);
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApplu);

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000);
  });
});

incrementScore = (num) => {
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
};
startGame();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with-devide=width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HW Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="sub-header">
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/betterlogo2.png" /></a>
        <div class="nav-links">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="file:///C:/stuffs/Comp%20Sci/Website/index.html">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="file:///C:/stuffs/Comp%20Sci/Website/Quiz.html"
                >QUIZES</a
              >
            </li>
            <li><a href="">LEARN MORE</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="file:///C:/stuffs/Comp%20Sci/Website/about.html.html"
                >ABOUT</a
              >
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </nav>
      <h1>Quiz Time!</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="hw-work-quiz">
      <div class="hwcontainer">
        <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
          <div id="hud">
            <div class="hud-item">
              <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">Question</p>
              <div id="progressBar">
                <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
              </div>
           </div>
            <div class="hud-item">
              <p class="hud-prefix">Score</p>
              <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">0</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1 id="question">What is the answer to this question?</h1>
          <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number-'1'>Choice 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number-'2'>Choice 2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number-'3'>Choice 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="choice-container">
            <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
            <p class="choice-text" data-number-'4'>Choice 4</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="footer">
      <h4>Want To Know Even More?</h4>
      <p>
        We are here to answer any of your questions, anytime, anywhere. You can
        contact us at:
      </p>
      <div class="icons">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linked"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-o"></i>
        <p>Made with love by Creator</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

So whats is wrong?...
Edit: I think I fixed the questions/question id thing but I still havent gotten anywhere, I can press any option, it will give me 100 score but wont change the button to the respective color (green if correct or red if wrong) and it wont move to the next question... WHY???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

the id you put in `const question = document.querySelector("#questions");` is questions but the id you declared in html is question. again take a look at your namings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited the suggestions you gave me, still no success, I updated the code provided too, I hope I got all the mistakes?

Comment: @SyrConcrete
another problem is you are trying to change the value of 'const SCORE_POINTS' using 'incrementScore'. check and see if there is such problems in other parts too.